# Cosets of SL(2,R) in GL(2,R)

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-groups

Describe the left cosets of $SL(2, 3)$ in $GL(2, 3)$.

Describe the left cosets of $SL(2, R)$ in $GL(2, R)$.

I think I have an idea of how to do the second part but I don't know how to describe the first.

Let $G = GL(2, R)$ and $S = SL(2, R)$. Let $g \in GL(2, R)$.

The left coset of $SL(2, R)$ in $GL(2, R)$ can be represented $gSL(2, R) = [gs: s \in SL(2, R), \det(s) = 1]$. I know that $\det(g) \neq 0$ because it is invertible.

I don't know how to proceed further for either part.

Comment: Hint - for any $g \in GL_2$ find an 'easy' element (think only non-zero diagonal entries) with the same determinant.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear - 'easy' = an element with entries equal to zero off diagonal. Given g find an 'easy' one to represent it mod $SL_2$

Comment: @peterag What if I use, $g = I$ identity?  If I multiply that with each element of $SL(2,3)$ I would obviously get a coset of just all the elements in $SL(2,3)$. Would that work?

Comment: See below ! But honestly, you might be better off talking with someone - by stack exchange this is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 5):

If $G$ is a group, and $H$ a subgroup, a way of understanding this question (the way I suggested in the comments above) is that it is asking you to write $G$ as a disjoint union, i.e., $$G = \bigcup_g\, gH, $$ for a choice of 'nice' $g$, where $g_1H \cap g_2H = \emptyset$ iff $g_1 \ne g_2$.

Another way of understanding the question (@Omnomnomnom's suggestion - sometimes a better way) is to have some criterion that characterizes the cosets $gH$.

But from your conversation with @Omnomnomnom it doesn't feel you are comfortable with all this... Let me first take another warm-up example:

Suppose instead your group $G = \mathbb R^*$, the set of non-zero real numbers. It's a group, viewed multiplicatively.

Let $H = \mathbb R^+$, the strictly positive (non-zero) real numbers - it's a subgroup: the product of two positive numbers is positive, etc.

Now, $xH = yH$ iff $x = yh$, where $h\in H$, i.e., $h$ is a positive number. This happens iff $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. Agree?  Arguably 'nice' representative choices to distinguish between the positives and negatives are $1$ and $-1$, and we can write (a coset decomposition)
$$ G = 1  \cdot H \ \cup \ (-1)H,$$
where the union is disjoint: if $x$ is positive, then by definition $x\in H$, and $x= 1 \cdot x \in 1H$, and $x$ belongs to the first coset; on the other hand, if $x$ is negative, then $x = -1 \cdot |x| \in -1\cdot H$, and $x$ belongs to the second coset.

So the above (disjoint) union is a 'nice' presentation of $G/H$, i.e of the decomposition of $G$ into cosets. @Omnomnomnom's way is to say that we broke $G$ up into the set of positive and negative numbers.

Back to the real question:

Here $G$ = invertible $2\times 2$ matrices, and $H$ the set of matrices of determinant $1$. As in your conversation with @Omnomnomnom, the point is that $\det g' = \det g$ if and only if there exists $h$, of determinant $1$, such that $g'= g h$ [explicitly solving for $h$: $h = g^{-1}g'$ has determinant $1$ iff $\det g' = \det g$.], i.e. $g'H = g H$.  (The role of 'same determinant' here is therefore the same as 'same sign'  before - Check that you understand that! )

So to decompose $G$ into $H$ cosets is to break $G$ up into subsets of elements with the same determinant  - @Omnomnomnom's suggestion - which is absolutely fine here - because all such subsets are of the form $gH$, for  ('nice' I suggested, but it doesn't really matter) representative choices of $g$. I was suggesting, if your arbitrary $g'$ has determinant $d$,  you find a 'nice' diagonal matrix $g$ with determinant $d$. If so $g'\in gH$, and one has a 'nice' description of the cosets...

So - given $d\ne 0$, can you find a diagonal matrix with determinant $d$?

I hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent explanation! I hope this makes things click for the asker.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that they're expecting an answer along the lines of
$$
g\,S = \{h \in G: \det(h) = \det(g)\}
$$
I think it is worth trying to convince yourself that this is the case.  It turns out that the same is true for matrices over $\Bbb F_3$.  Note that this means that $SL(2,3)$ has exactly *two* cosets.

Comment: I wonder if they mean for you to describe the quotient group $G/S$.  Have you learned about quotient groups yet?

Comment: We haven't learned that yet. Also I like your name. My question is why is it that $det(h) = det(g)$ ? I know $g$ is invertible but that doesn't necessarily imply that its determinant is 1. Secondly, why are there only two cosets of $SL(2,3)$ if there are numerous ways in a set of $[0,1,2]$ to get a determinant of 1 that is also invertible.

Comment: Note that $\det(gs) = \det(g)\det(s)$

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your "secondly..."

Comment: Ok so since $det (gs) = det(g)det(s)$ and $det(s) = 1$, $det(gs) = det(g)$. That makes sense. Let me ask a different question about the "Secondly," part as that was confusing. What are those two cosets?

Comment: One coset is $S$ itself, the set of all matrices with determinant $1$.  The other coset is the set of all matrices with determinant $-1$.

Comment: Also, why did you take $h \in G$ when we already have $g \in G$? Couldn't we just say that $det(gs) = det (g)$ so then $gs  \in SL(2,R)$?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense.  I think the answer here is to say that I'm trying to describe the coset as a subset of $G$ without simply stating the definition of a coset.

Comment: Couldn't we just say that $gS = det (g)$?

Comment: I thought that $SL(2,3)$ was the set of $2x2$ matrices with determinant 1 and numbers in the matrices from $Z_3$. Why would there be only two cosets? I am confused as to how you got $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: $g$ is a matrix.  $S$ is a set.  $gS$ is a set, and $\det(g)$ is a number.  We certainly **cannot** say $gS = \det(g)$.  Do you know what a coset is?

Comment: From what I understand about the way my book describes it, A coset is a set of elements formed by taking each element of a given subgroup and then multiplying but an element from the group that contains the subgroup. Depending on which comes first it forms the left or right subgroup. So I guess every coset formed in this case would be the product of an arbitrary $g \in G$ and every element of the subgroup. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: So then when representing this coset, why are we taking the determinant of $g$ and $s$ if all we are doing is multiplying $g$ with $s$ as per the definition of cosets? I thought that $SL(2,R)$ was a set of matrices not determinants.

Comment: fyi I continuously referred to your answer in mine - from experience, I know that the '@' does not get picked up in an answer, even though it does in a comment.